# How can I distinguish between different structures of actual function parameters?

Tags: programming, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Overloading functions for different types of parameters is very powerful.
I can easily write different versions of a function depending on the function parameters being Integer, Real, Complex, Sring List and so on.

Now I want to write function which operates on data structures looking like this:

`{_String, _List}`
Example: `{"my data structure", {1,2,3,4,5}}`

My function shall also operate either

- two strings (containing file names) plus an optional third one which
  can be either "CSV" or "TSV"

Examples: `f["file1","fiel2"]`   or   `f["file1","fiel2","TSV"]`

or on

- an arbitrary number>2 of strings (containing file names but neither
  "CSV" or "TSV") plus an optional last parameter which can be either
  "CSV" or "TSV"

Examples: `f["file1","fiel2","file3"]`   or   `f["file1","fiel2","file3","TSV"]`

- or a string (containing a file name) as first parameter,  a data
  structure of the type described above as second one plus an optional
  third one which can be either "CSV" or "TSV"

Examples: `f["file1",{"my data structure", {1,2,3}}]`   or  `f["file1",{"my data structure", {1,2,3}}, "CSV"]`

I did it like this:

```
Remove[f];
dataStruct={_String, _List};
f[a_String, b_String, type_:"CSV"]:=Print["1. variant with two Strings, type=", type];
f[a_String, b:dataStruct, type_:"CSV"]:=Print["2. variant with String and dataStruct, type=", type];
f[a:dataStruct, b:dataStruct, type_:"CSV"]:=Print["3. variant with two dataStruct, type=", type];
f[{a_String, b_String, ___String}, type_:"CSV"]:=Print["4. variant with List of Strings, type=", type];

f["foo", "bar"]
f["foo", "bar", "CSV"]
```

work as expected.

```
f["foo", "bar", "metrics"]
```

returns the last parameter "metrics" as type instead of matching the fourth definition.

```
f["foo", {"bar", {}}]
f["foo", {"bar", {}}, "CSV"]
```

invoke the second definition

```
f[{"foo", {1, 2}}, {"bar", {3, 4, 5}}]
```

takes the third variant.

How can I cope with this?

Comment: Aren't you missing the enclosing `List` in your `"metrics"` example?

Comment: Yes, your observation is perfectly right! `f[{"foo", "bar", "metrics"}]` and `f[{"foo", "bar", "metrics"}, "CSV"]` use the fourth definition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use symbols for the filetype (it will force disambiguation):

```
Remove[g];
dataStruct = {_String, _List};
g[a_String, b_String, type_Symbol : CSV] := Print["1. variant with two Strings, type=", type];
g[a_String, b : dataStruct, type_Symbol : CSV] := Print["2. variant with String and dataStruct, type=", type];
g[a : dataStruct, b : dataStruct, type_Symbol : CSV] := Print["3. variant with two dataStruct, type=", type];
g[a_String, b_String, ___String, type_Symbol : CSV] := Print["4. variant with List of Strings, type=", type];
```

`g["foo", "bar", "metrics"]` gives `4. variant with List of Strings, type=CSV`

Another would be to use options instead of default arguments:

```
Remove[h];
Options[h] = {MyFileType -> "CSV"};
dataStruct = {_String, _List};
h[a_String, b_String, OptionsPattern[]] := Print["1. variant with two Strings, type=", OptionValue[MyFileType]];
h[a_String, b : dataStruct, OptionsPattern[]] := Print["2. variant with String and dataStruct, type=", OptionValue[MyFileType]];
h[a : dataStruct, b : dataStruct, OptionsPattern[]] := Print["3. variant with two dataStruct, type=", OptionValue[MyFileType]];
h[a_String, b_String, ___String, OptionsPattern[]] := Print["4. variant with List of Strings, type=", OptionValue[MyFileType]];
```

`h["foo", "bar", "metrics"]` gives `4. variant with List of Strings, type=CSV`

`h["foo", {"bar", {}}, MyFileType -> "TSV"]` gives `2. variant with String and dataStruct, type=TSV`

Another would be to use more specific representations than String, maybe a special head. But without knowing your semantics, I have no specific suggestion along those lines.

I generally avoid default argument values. It seems to inevitably bump up against ambiguities as your method signatures evolve. Without further info, I think options is probably the cleanest way to go.

Comment: Thank you lericr for your detailed discussion and two alternative advices. The first one, to request a Symbol for the default argument is more handy since it requires less changing of existing code and it is less typing. However, the comment above your reply shows that I also fell for a catastrophic clerical error. Nevertheless, many thanks!